# Angular 2+ Attempting to input data from parent to child component

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to input data into a child component which is an object within an object.
I have 2 Models:

**Tiles:**

```
import { Tile } from "./tile";

export class Tiles {
    public tileOne: Tile;
}
```

**Tile**

```
export class Tile {
    public squareId: number;
}
```

My parent class, **Board**

```
export class BoardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const tiles = new Tiles();
    tiles.tileOne = new Tile();
    tiles.tileOne.squareId = 1;
  }
}
```

and the template:

```
<div class="row row-1">
   <square class="square-component" [tile]="tiles.tileOne"></square>
</div>
```

and the child class, **square**:

```
export class SquareComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tile: Tile;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The console is throwing this error:

> 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tileOne' of undefined'

Which I don't understand why `tileOne` would be `'undefined'` as it's initialized in the `ngOnInit` of the board class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try    const tiles = new Tiles(); in the constructor, could be your view is loaded first and then the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in the code that you provided the tiles object is not assigned to the component. Thus, it will not be available in the template. Try:

```
public tiles: Tiles;

ngOnInit() {
    const tiles = new Tiles();
    tiles.tileOne = new Tile();
    tiles.tileOne.squareId = 1;

    this.tiles = tiles;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, managed to get it working and now i'm kicking myself that I didn't assign it to the component in the first place, a mistake I hope I wont make again :P

Answer (score 0):

Add a safe navigation operator to check if the value is there,

```
 <square class="square-component" [tile]="tiles?.tileOne"></square>
```

**EDIT**

You need to assign the value using **this**

```
ngOnInit() {
    const tiles = new Tiles();
    tiles.tileOne = new Tile();
    tiles.tileOne.squareId = 1;
    this.tiles = tiles;
}
```

Comment: That stops the error from occuring, but in the child class the tile object is null.

Comment: which one is null?

Comment: the tile object that is in the square component.
In the ngOnInit I wrote
Console.log(this.tile);

Which returned 'null'

Comment: Thank you for your help, with a combination of your response and SiliconSouls response I was able to get it working. 
Turned out I wasn't binding the tiles object to the board component but only creating it in the ngOnInIt.

Comment: yeah thats what i mentioned, glad you got it sorted, upvote if this helped